# oracle bulkcopy from vb.net databale

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am loading the CSV file to vb.net datatable .
then I am using  Bulk copy command to write to database.

The problem is if one date cell in the data table is empty, i am receiving

ORA:-01840 input value not long enough for date format.

How to resolve this.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim cn As New OracleConnection("Data Source =(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ipaddressofserver)(PORT = portofserver))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = oracleservicename)) ) ; User Id=useridofdb;Password=passwordofdb")
        cn.Open()
        MsgBox("connection opened")
        Dim dt As DataTable = ReadCSV("D:\test.csv")
 DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
 Try            
            Dim _bulkCopy As New OracleBulkCopy(cn)
            _bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TEST_TABLE"
            _bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 10800
            _bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)
            cn.Close()
            cn.Dispose()
            cn = Nothing
            MsgBox("Finished")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
 Function ReadCSV(ByVal path As String) As System.Data.DataTable
        Try
            Dim sr As New StreamReader(path)
            Dim fullFileStr As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
            sr.Close()
            sr.Dispose()
            Dim lines As String() = fullFileStr.Split(ControlChars.Lf)
            Dim recs As New DataTable()
            Dim sArr As String() = lines(0).Split(","c)
            For Each s As String In sArr
                recs.Columns.Add(New DataColumn())
            Next
            Dim row As DataRow
            Dim finalLine As String = ""
            For Each line As String In lines
                row = recs.NewRow()
                finalLine = line.Replace(Convert.ToString(ControlChars.Cr), "")
                row.ItemArray = finalLine.Split(","c)
                recs.Rows.Add(row)
            Next
 Return recs
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: added the code which i am using. First it is loading to one data table using ReadCSV function. So all columns will be in string format. My data contains some date columns and decimal columns. Some times date and decimal will be null .

Comment: Can you provide 1-2 lines of your CSV?

Comment: The acutal issue found: the comma seperated values is ,, in one line(value is not there and is blank). and the datatable column is System.Decimal. and receiving the error "Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <> in test  Column.  Expected type is Decimal"